# How to get application package name which can use our api in our server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

I would like to store the Android application package name of a specific demo or other app so developers can use my API from my server. And I would like the detail from background without them knowing.

I am an Android developer, so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: bascially you like to track the api users ???

Comment: yes does there is any way to create a log of that package name in our server log file?

Comment: fine! what you have done so for

Comment: not sure that I understand you. Do you want to write a server-side app that will have limited access, only for the listed android applications?

Comment: i already created get api for my application but i can't able to find any reference code to put the security like this to get the package name of other spam users. Please can you give me and referral demo link?

Comment: @2oppin ya i just only need to create a log for api in my server by who can use my api rather than me. so i need all accessor android application package name

Comment: one of the simple way is , making the credentials (authenticate) the user before using the API

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, But have a look at CORS.

Comment: @Harisudhan.A i think u r saying for token auth credentials. Am i right?

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal, what you need called authentication. It all depends of what the conditions of using your server. the most simpe way is JWT,
it's maybe possible to track if there is a finit list of apps that may pass some additional info in the headers of requests